# brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError when calling a function from contract using Brownie

Tags: python, brownie

Encountering the following issues calling a contract w/ `Brownie v1.14.6` on `mainnet-fork` w/ infura. Note that `pool_lens = interface.FusePoolLens("0x8dA38681826f4ABBe089643D2B3fE4C6e4730493")`.

```py
>>> data = pool_lens.getPublicPoolUsersWithData(int(1e18), {'from': accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0xb94bc63cf4108c9e36789a7fc9e36069e36ad7f8f61c16b4101325d9bb277166
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 506, in _await_confirmation
    print(self._confirm_output())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 564, in _confirm_output
    revert_msg = self.revert_msg if web3.supports_traces else None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 49, in wrapper
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return fn(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 257, in revert_msg
    self._get_trace()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 604, in _get_trace
    raise RPCRequestError(msg) from None
brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Encountered a ConnectionError while requesting `debug_traceTransaction`. The local RPC client has likely crashed.
^C  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 1676, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 1550, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/account.py", line 688, in transfer
    receipt = self._await_confirmation(receipt, required_confs, gas_strategy, gas_iter)
  File "eth_brownie-1.14.6-py3.9.egg/brownie/network/account.py", line 734, in _await_confirmation
    raise exc.with_traceback(None)
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

It then sits on that error indefinitely until I ctrl-c out of it. The `tx.logs`, `tx.events`, and `tx.trace` are all empty, while this is what the `tx.info()` looks like:

```py
>>> tx.info()
Transaction was Mined (reverted)
---------------------
Tx Hash: 0xb94bc63cf4108c9e36789a7fc9e36069e36ad7f8f61c16b4101325d9bb277166
From: 0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871
To: 0x8dA38681826f4ABBe089643D2B3fE4C6e4730493
Value: 0
Function: FusePoolLens.getPublicPoolUsersWithData
Block: 12847838
Gas Used: 11812914 / 12000000 (98.4%)
```

I'm trying to rewrite the Rari Fuse liquidator bot in Python/Brownie, you can see the source code line I'm following [here](https://github.com/Rari-Capital/fuse-liquidator-bot/blob/master/index.js#L115) and abi/contract location [here](https://docs.rari.capital/contracts/#general). You can infer how the function return is supposed to look based on how the source code handles it. Changing the first parameter (specified as `maxHealth` per the abi) to 100 has the same issue.

Interestingly, other call on this contract work fine. For example `check = pool_lens.getUserSummary("0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871", {'from': accounts[0]})` runs as expected. **However**, `check.return_value` encounters the same issue as the above function (`brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Encountered a ConnectionError while requesting 'debug_traceTransaction'. The local RPC client has likely crashed.`). This leads me to believe the issue is with Brownie itself/my local Brownie.

I am well under the request limit on Infura, and do not have any rate-limiting options set.

Comment: I see `KeyboardInterrupt:` and that usually means you hit a key to kill it. Was that what happened?

Comment: Yup! Everything up to the brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError occurs naturally, and then it sits there indefinitely until I ctrl-c out, which is the `KeyboardInterrupt` you're seeing. You can even see the ^C character where it occurs.

Comment: Ah ok... so it's getting stuck somewhere. Could you maybe uninstall and reinstall and see if that helps? What network is this on?

Comment: Just used `pipx reinstall eth-brownie`, encountering the same issue. Running on ethereum `mainnet-fork`.